# Inserting Null values to Mysql database from Sheets using Google Apps Script

Tags: mysql, sql, google-apps-script, jdbc, google-sheets

I'm currently working on a data ingestion add-on using Google apps script. The main idea is that the users of an application can insert data from sheets to a database. To do so, i'm using the JDBC api that apps script provides

The problem i'm currently having is that when I read a cell from the sheet that is empty apps script uses the type undefined, therefore producing an error a the moment of insertion. How could I do such thing?

My current insert function:

```
function putData(row, tableName) {
  var connectionName = '****';
  var user = '****';
  var userPwd = '*****';
  var db = '******';

  var dbUrl = 'jdbc:google:mysql://' + connectionName + '/' + db;
  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var data = row
  var query = "INSERT INTO "+ db + '.' + tableName +" VALUES (" ;
  var i = 0

  //The following loop is just to build the query from the rows taken from the sheet
  // if the value is a String I add quotation marks
  for each (item in row){
    if ((typeof item) == 'string'){
      if (i == row.length-1){
        query += "'" + item + "'";
      } else {
        query += "'" + item + "',";
      } 
    }else {
      if (i == row.length-1){
        query += item;
      } else {
        query += item + ",";
      } 
    }
  i++
  }
  query += ")"
  results = stmt.executeUpdate(query)
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
}
```

When I try to insert the word "NULL" in some cases in thinks it is a string and brings out an error on other fields.

Comment: I think you can test for it’s truthiness and it’s type. If truthiness is false then insert null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to get the data from the Spreadsheet, more precisely from a cell, the value will be automatically parsed to one of these types: `Number`, `Boolean`, `Date` or `String`.

According to the [Google getValues() documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues):

> The values may be of type `Number`, `Boolean`, `Date`, or `String`, depending on the value of the cell. Empty cells are represented by an empty string in the array.

So essentially, the `undefined` type may be an issue present in the way you pass the `row` parameter (for example, trying to access cells which are out of bounds).

If you want to solve your issue, you should add an `if` statement right after the `for each (item in row) {` line:

```
if (typeof item == 'undefined')
  item = null;
```

The `if` statement checks if the `row` content is of type `undefined` and if so, it automatically parses it to `null`. In this way, the content will be of type `null` and you should be able to insert it into the database.

The recommended way to do what you are doing actually is by using the [`JDBC Prepared Statements`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-prepared-statement), which are basically precompiled SQL statements, making it easier for you to insert the necessary data. More exactly, you wouldn't have to manually prepare data for the insertion, like you did in the code you provided above. They are also the safer way, making your data less prone to various attacks.

Also, the `for each...in` statement is a deprecated one and you should consider using something else instead such as the `for` loop or the `while` loop.

Furthermore, I suggest you take a look at these links, since they might be of help:

1. [Class JdbcPreparedStatement](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-prepared-statement);
2. [Class Range Apps Script - getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).

Comment: It worked perfectly! It turns out it did return '' not "undefined".